# RegEx match parent items containing duplicates

Tags: php, regex, duplicates

The title is probably confusing, but I have no idea how to properly phrase this.

So here's my goal. I have this string (or something like it):

`[some_element]Random string chars [some_element]Ramdon[/some_element] some more random chars[/some_element]`

(Some of you may recognize that these are WordPress shortcodes, but this methodology would still be useful elsewhere to me as well.)

What I need to do is match the parent "element". My usual approach might be something like this:

`\[(\w+)].*?\[\/\1]`

The problem is, this won't work in the above example, because it's "child element" has a the same closing "tag".

How could I get this regex to work, reglardless of how many nested children exist (literally, an infinite number of duplicate nested children)?

Comment: This is a great example of when regex is *not* the right tool for the job.

Comment: What language/tool are you using for regex?

Comment: @Biffen ...okay, then what is the right tool?

Comment: @anubhava PHP is the language

Comment: @Biffen then do something productive and tell the OP what *is* the right tool.

Comment: @JoelWorsham There's no one right tool. If this is a common syntax there might be a library that can parse it. Otherwise one might have to write one's own parser. In the latter case there are other libraries to make that easier, but without a language tag it's hard to recommend anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [recursive regex in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php):

```
$re = '~\s* ( \[some_element\] ( (?: .* | (?1) )* ) \[/some_element\] )~x';
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eP7cS4/1)

This will give you this string in matched group #2:

```
Random string chars [some_element]Ramdon[/some_element] some more random chars
```

Comment: Whoah, this seems like it will work. I don't know a ton about regex, and I haven't heard of this before, but I think it's exactly what I was looking for. I'll learn more about this, but I think you got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [recursive patterns (in php)](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).
But I am sadly way too inexperienced to write the pattern here without trying :(
Maybe you can figure that out yourself. I am going to try it too, but that's gonna take a while...

would you look at that:

(The words between {[< and >]} are not part of the pattern, they describe what the subpattern should do.)

> [ ( ( {[< some way to match any string except [word] >]} ) | (?R) )* ]

Comment: Your answer is definitely what I'm looking for, just not an exact answer to my question like @anubhava's was. Thank you though! Upvote forsure.